# ACL not getting enabled in consul

Tags: amazon-web-services, consul

I have setup consul on a single instance. The `web-ui` is running perfectly but the ACL are not enabled. Previously I was not having any config file but now I have created a `config.json` file in `/etc/consul.d/bootstrap/` with the following content.

```
{
    "bootstrap": true,
    "server": true,
    "datacenter": "dc1",
    "acl_datacenter": "dc1",
    "data_dir": "/var/consul",
    "encrypt": "consul keygen output",
    "ca_file": "/etc/consul.d/ssl/ca.cert",
    "cert_file": "/etc/consul.d/ssl/consul.cert",
    "key_file": "/etc/consul.d/ssl/consul.key",
    "verify_incoming": true,
    "verify_outgoing": true,
    "log_level": "INFO",
    "enable_syslog": true
}
```

Than I ran the following command

> consul agent -server -bootstrap  -data-dir /tmp/consul -ui-dir
>   /home/ubuntu/dist/ -client=X.X.X.X

where `X.X.X.X` is the private ip of my instance

But the ACL are not getting enabled.

> /etc/consul.d/server/config.json

```
{
    "bootstrap": false,
    "server": false,
    "log_level": "DEBUG",
    "enable_syslog": true,
    "datacenter": "dc1",
    "data_dir": "/var/consul",
    "ui_dir": "/home/ubuntu/dist",
    "acl_datacenter": "dc1"
    "encrypt": "SECRET"
}
```

> /etc/consul.d/server/config.json

```
{
    "bootstrap": false,
    "server": true,
    "log_level": "DEBUG",
    "enable_syslog": true,
    "datacenter": "dc1",
    "data_dir": "/var/consul",
    "acl_datacenter": "dc1",
    "acl_default_policy": "allow",
    "encrypt": "SECRET"
}
```

Working config file

```
{
    "bootstrap": true,
    "server": true,
    "log_level": "DEBUG",
    "enable_syslog": true,
    "datacenter": "dc1",
    "addresses" : {
      "http": "X.X.X.X"
    },
    "bind_addr": "X.X.X.X",
    "node_name": "X.X.X.X",
    "data_dir": "/tmp/consul",
    "ui_dir": "~/dist",
    "acl_datacenter": "dc1",
    "acl_master_token": "secret",
    "encrypt": "secret"
}
```

Now run the following command

```
consul agent -config-dir ~/server -ui-dir ~/dist -bootstrap true -client=X.X.X.X
```

Comment: Since you are only running the single instance please post the configuration of your `config.json` present in `/etc/consul.d/server` and  `/etc/consul.d/client` directories .

Comment: @AnkitKulkarni Added the content of required 'config.json' file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the master token in your configuration. If you add this,

`"acl_master_token": "secret"`, and use the same token in your UI, you should be able to use the ACL.

Note: If you are using a single node instance, do not set the `acl_token` property same as your master token. This would mean anyone with access to the UI would have access to the `master token`, essentially bypassing all your ACL rules. This property should only be set only on server nodes.

After getting it running well, I created a screencast to demonstrate how to setup `consul` on a single server. [Here is the link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVKveB-2bGQ)

Comment: I didn't get your point, "do not set acl_token property same as your master token"

Comment: `acl_master_token` is like the expected token, to edit ACL's. And `acl_token` is the token submitted by that client/server. Only servers should have `acl_token` same as `acl_master_token`. Setting them same on a client would disable your ACL.

Comment: I added the acl_master_token in bootstrap config and server config file. Also added the same token to the web-ui under setting section. And started consul by the command 'consul agent -server -bootstrap  -data-dir /tmp/consul -ui-dir /home/ubuntu/dist/ -client=X.X.X.X' still it shows ACL are disabled.

Comment: I have uploaded a sample bootstrap config at, https://gist.github.com/cskksc/ad0862509dbfe177debc. 
Run this using `consul agent -config-dir ~/consul_config -ui-dir ~/consul_config/dist -bootstrap true` and then enter `secret` in your web ui as a token (rightmost gear button).

Comment: I tried this way also. Made a `config.json` file as per the configuration mentioned in your sample bootstrap config. Started consul with command mentioned by you and visited the url 'http://example.com:8500/ui` it gives an error `HTTP error code from Consul: 0 error`

Comment: It running now. Your trick was working but on localhost, i.e. the web-ui wasn't accessible through public i.p but it was accessible through localhost curl request. So I added the http binding address in the configuration file and ran your command with -client=X.X.X.X option. I am adding the final working config file content in the question itself. So add it to your answer and I will accept it.